# Does the first rank of "upgrade" skills provide any benefit?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I noticed that the first rank of "Fitness" provides an extremely powerful upgrade:

[image]

However, the next level provides a much smaller upgrade, but displays a "green bar" showing what is actually being improved:

[image]

So does this mean the first rank (for a measly 1 point) really give me 15% health, shield and melee damage bonus, while the second rank (2 points) only gives 10% more health and shield? Is this how all skills work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does provide that benefit for a very cheap price. For active powers, the first rank also unlocks them so that you can use them. Putting 1 or 2 points into every skill at the beginning is a good way to open up all options for combat and to get some cheap bonuses.

Be aware that all bonuses are additive, so if you have a 15% bonus and a 10% bonus this will always just result in a 25% bonus, not a 1 * 1.15 * 1.10 bonus.